# tweenlite: tweening multiple objects at once

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface, gsap

I would like to know if I can get an error or some other problems when I try to tween several objects like this and using an onComplete-property:

```
TweenLite.to(restartBtn, .5, {alpha:0});
TweenLite.to(mainMenuBtn, .5, {alpha:0, onComplete:quitFadeIn});
```

What I want to do is fade out several objects at once and when they finished a special function gets called. Are there other possibilities when using tweenlite available or do I have to use timelinelite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sample code should work without any errors and if you're limited to TweenLite, this is a perfectly good method to use.

If you can use TweenMax which is the same as TweenLite, just with more features, you can use something like this to tween multiple items:

```
TweenMax.allTo([restartBtn, mainMenuBtn], .5, {alpha:0, onComplete:quitFadeIn});
```

and this would stagger the fades by .2 seconds

```
TweenMax.allTo([restartBtn, mainMenuBtn], .5, {alpha:0, onComplete:quitFadeIn}, -.2);
```

Comment: Ah!! Thank you very much!:) Now I know how to optimize all my tweens with tweenMax. You made my life easier!